# Oracle - What happens when refreshing a 'REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND' view with DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have the following materialized view -

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TESTRESULT 
ON PREBUILT TABLE WITH REDUCED PRECISION
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE...
```

This materialized view has no backing MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG.  As seen in the clause above this MV has "ON DEMAND" specifies, and according to Oracle documentation,

> "[ON DEMAND] indicate[s] that the materialized
>   view will be refreshed on demand by
>   calling one of the three DBMS_MVIEW
>   refresh procedures."

When I call DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TESTRESULT') , what is occuring?  Is it manually checking each record to see if it has been updated?

Oracle Version: 10g

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default (and this default changes in different versions of Oracle), that will do a full, atomic refresh on the materialized view.  That means that the data in the materialized view will be deleted, the underlying query will be re-executed, and the results will be loaded into the materialized view.  You can make the refresh more efficient by passing in a value of FALSE for the `ATOMIC_REFRESH` parameter, i.e.

```
dbms_mview.refresh( 'TESTRESULT', atomic_refresh => false );
```

That will cause the materialized view to be truncated, the query re-executed, and the results inserted into the materialized view via a direct path insert.  That will be more efficient than an atomic refresh but the materialized view will be empty during the refresh.

Comment: +1 @Justin.. Also, what happens if I have created the MVIEW with `NOLOGGING`? The MVIEW I have created, keeps erring out with UNDOTBS small.. Will `ATOMIC_REFRESH` help?

Comment: @guru - If I understand correctly, you're getting an ORA-01555 error, right?  That implies that the problem is that the tables you're querying are changing and your refresh is unable to produce a consistent view of the data as it existed when the refresh started.  Normally, that would imply that the `UNDO_RETENTION` parameter and/or the UNDO tablespace is too small and should be increased.  Potentially, you could also look to decrease the amount of time required to do the refresh which `ATOMIC_REFRESH` would accomplish.

Comment: Am away from my office PC, I need to wait to get the exact ORA error. When searched, Tom Kyte too has mentioned about 01555. But here is what I do. I create a MVIEW based on a big table. It takes around 40-60 mins. The MVIEW size is 35-40 GB. When I refresh (Complete) it with `DBMS_MVIEW`, the script runs for 2-3 hrs and errors out with MVIEW REFRESH PATH size being an issue.